# Ubuntu 12.04 on ASUS X55C

Tags: 12.04, asus

I've bought a new [ASUS X55C laptop](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/Versatile_Performance/X55C/), with no OS preinstaled (only DOS). I've installed Win7, since I got in box cd with Win7 drivers, and everything works fine.

Now, I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 (dualboot), and I tried it (from CD, without installation). I noticed that my network isn't worknig (wifi, LAN), keyboard commands doesn't work fine, etc...

I googled for ubuntu drivers, but all I've founded is [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201206-11379/components/). My question is this:

Can anyone tell me is Ubuntu going to work fine (network, keyboard,...) when I install it, although it doesn't work on "Try Ubuntu" mode? I wouldn't like to install OS that wouldn't work.

Here is the output of commands you asked for.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci -n

00:00.0 0600: 8086:0104 (rev 09)        
00:02.0 0300: 8086:0116 (rev 09)    
00:14.0 0c03: 8086:1e31 (rev 04)    
00:16.0 0780: 8086:1e3a (rev 04)    
00:1a.0 0c03: 8086:1e2d (rev 04)    
00:1b.0 0403: 8086:1e20 (rev 04)    
00:1c.0 0604: 8086:1e10 (rev c4)    
00:1c.1 0604: 8086:1e12 (rev c4)    
00:1c.3 0604: 8086:1e16 (rev c4)    
00:1d.0 0c03: 8086:1e26 (rev 04)    
00:1f.0 0601: 8086:1e59 (rev 04)    
00:1f.2 0106: 8086:1e03 (rev 04)    
00:1f.3 0c05: 8086:1e22 (rev 04)    
02:00.0 0280: 1814:3290    
02:00.1 0d11: 1814:3298    
03:00.0 0200: 1969:1091 (rev 10)
```

and

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -C network

  *-network UNCLAIMED     

       description: Network controller    
       product: Ralink corp.    
       vendor: Ralink corp.    
       physical id: 0    
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0    
       version: 00    
       width: 32 bits    
       clock: 33MHz   
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list    
       configuration: latency=0   
       resources: memory:f7d10000-f7d1ffff

  *-network UNCLAIMED

       description: Ethernet controller    
       product: AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet    
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.    
       physical id: 0    
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0    
       version: 10    
       width: 64 bits    
       clock: 33MHz    
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list    
       configuration: latency=0    
       resources: memory:f7c00000-f7c3ffff ioport:e000(size=128)
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer (without deeper research): it is highly unlikely that a component that fails in the live system will work in the installed system without extra work. Thats one of the purposes for Ubuntu Live CDs.

Answer (score -1):

I bought the same and tried Ubuntu 12.04. Which is good choice to work.  But sometimes WiFi will not functioning. It showed me like disabled.

So I just fold the laptop, it will be in the standby or sleep mode. Then I will reopen it. Then the Wi-Fi will connected automatically.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/492074)

Comment: I am new to this forum. I don't have enough reputations to comment here.